# Why is my scope variable not binding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a nested controller inside an ng-repeat as shown below. My problem is that my scope variables aren't binding, and the button doesn't reach the scope function either.. I have a controller set up and have the values assigned, it initializes and runs through fine but after this I am not presented with any values in the view.

```
<div ng-repeat="field in model.fieldData | filter:filterFn">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        .....
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div ng-controller="commentsCtrl">
            <p>{{field.Id}}...{{model.text}}</p>
            <button type="button" ng-click="createComment()">New</button>          
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

angular.module('main').controller('commentsCtrl', [
'$scope', '$modal', 'connectionService', 'fieldService',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $modal, connectionService, fieldService) {
        $scope = {};
        $scope.model = {};
        $scope.model.text = "test for view";
        $scope.createComment = function(){
            ...this never gets hit
        };
    }
]);
```

**Edit-Solved**: I have declared $scope = {} which has reset my whole scope.. fantastic

Comment: `$scope = {};` - what?

Comment: @tymeJV thanks for pointing that out.. mustve put it in accidently when making the controller.. the longer you stare at these things the more normal they look.

Answer (score 5):

You are replacing the Angular `$scope` object, and consequently the behavior when you write:

```
$scope = {};
```

Remove that line and it will work.